# Check if more engineers are happy than not happy

Tags: java

I wish to use this sample to make my code more readable. Could you share with me your ideas on method naming, variable naming, `if`-statements etc.

It would be great if you have any `URL`s.

```
private boolean areEngineersHappy (List<Engineer> engineers) {
  int notHappyEngineers = 0;
  int happyEngineers = 0;
  for (Engineer engineer : engineers) {
    boolean notHappy = !engineer.isHappy();
    if (!notHappy) {
      happyEngineers++;
    }
    if (notHappy) {
      notHappyEngineers++;
    }
  }
  return happyEngineers > notHappyEngineers;
}
```

Comment: return "Engineers are never happy...";

Comment: @JonStory that should automatically evaluate to `true` within Java, except the engineers were unhappy with this and refused to put it in.

Comment: Do not close. Code is real enough to get good reviews, as has happened.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Consider

```
private boolean isMajorityHappy(List<Engineer> engineers) {
    int netHappiness = 0;

    for (Engineer engineer : engineers) {
        if (engineer.isHappy()) {
            netHappiness++;
        } else {
            netHappiness--;
        }
    }

    return netHappiness > 0;
}
```

Name the method based on what it does.  What it does is check if the majority of the members of the list are happy.  The fact that the list is of engineers is mostly beside the point.

I would expect `areEngineersHappy` to return false if any engineer is unhappy.

Note that we don't need two variables to tell if the majority is happy.  We can use a single variable and subtract for unhappy members of the list.  If `netHappiness` is positive, then the majority of the members of the list are happy.

I would try to avoid constructs like `if (! notHappy) {`.  It would be much simpler to change the logic around so that you can say `if (happy) {` instead.

You don't need to say `if (happy)` and `if (! happy)`.  This is exactly the situation for which an `else` is designed.

Comment: How about `return engineers.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.isHappy() ? 1 : -1).sum() > 0;`

Comment: This is the most readable and natural coding expression of this idea.  Does it without calling `engineers.size()`, also; very nice.

Comment: `engineers.size()` is generally (always?) implemented in O(1) time, so maybe you could return early if `netHappiness` is too large (resp. too low) for other engineers' mood to change the final outcome. I know, this is too *clever* ;-)

Comment: @coredump Unfortunately, not *always*. In Java's libraries it is, but I could make my own class that implements `List`, and not do so. It is always recommended that `List#size` be implemented in O(1) time, though.

Comment: @Justin You could also make your own class that implements `List` whose `iterator` method calls 911 and reports a hostage situation. Therefore, solutions that involve calling `iterator` must be bad.

Comment: @immibis, man, that list would come with a lot of dependencies ...

Answer (score 20):

Adding to [Manny Meng answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107581/how-can-i-make-this-method-more-readable/107583#107583)  if your main concern is readability and Java 8 is available you may want to use streams.

Something like this:

```
return engineers.stream().filter(Engineer::isHappy).count() > engineers.size() / 2;
```

EDIT (Due to some valid point in the comments regarding formatting. I myself don't like large one liners either):

```
int numHappy = engineers.stream().filter(Engineer::isHappy).count(); 
return numHappy > engineers.size() / 2;
```

Comment: Impressive, really cool.

Comment: That's less readable... (Although could be formatted to be more readable)

Comment: Yes your are right adding some break lines will improve it. But I still think is more readable without taking how is formatted into account.

Comment: Nice, but anyone who can understand that answer, will also understand @mdfst13's answer, so I would go with mdfst13's

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to try to avoid repeating what people have already said.

- If you look carefully at your code, you'll notice that nowhere do you access state. As it is, this function doesn't really belong to an object; it would be better as a static function:

  ```
  private static boolean mostlyHappy(List<Engineer> engineers) {
  ```
- What if someone had a class `SoftwareEngineer` that extends from `Engineer`? In that case, I cannot pass my `List<SoftwareEngineer>` to your function. So let's make that change as well:

  ```
  private static boolean mostlyHappy(List<? extends Engineer> engineers) {
  ```
- Variable names (as you specifically requested this):

  - `int notHappyEngineers`. Since "not happy" is equivalently "unhappy", I personally think it would be better to call this `int unhappyEngineers`. However, if I read `unhappyEngineers`, that doesn't tell me much about what it stores. I'd instead name this `int numUnhappy`. Similarly with `int happyEngineers`.

    ```
    int numUnhappy = 0;
    int numHappy = 0;
    ```
- Java 8. While your code is already reasonably readable, I think that using Java 8's streams will further improve readability:

  ```
  private static boolean mostlyHappy(List<? extends Engineer> engineers) {
      int numHappy = engineers.stream()
                              .filter(Engineer::isHappy)
                              .count();
      return numHappy > engineers.size() / 2;
  }
  ```

When using Java 8's streams, I believe it is important to put each operation on its own line. This makes it quick and easy to see what the code does, since I only need to read vertically, rather than try to parse horizontally.

Taking the above code as an example, here's my thought process upon reading it:

1. `filter`
2. `count`. Oh so we are counting the number of elements that match `filter`'s predicate.
3. `Engineer::isHappy`. We are counting the number of happy engineers. Great, that makes sense.

The indentation for the stream operations themselves is debatable. I'd probably end up with it looking something like this in my own code:

```
int numHappy = engineers.stream()
                   .filter(Engineer::isHappy)
                   .count();
```

Comment: I'd go with `happyCount` over `numHappy`.

Comment: @Celos That's definitely a better name.

Answer (score 13):

Some points:

1. Java conventions require indents to be 4-spaced, not 2-spaced, like almost any other language. ([Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf))
2. The space between the method name and the parentheses can be removed:

   ```
   areEngineersHappy (List<Engineer> engineers)
   ```
3. `areEngineersHappy` is not really a good name for a method. I would suggest perhaps `majorityEngineersHappy()`, but even mine I am not happy about.
4. Some code can also be simplified:

   ```
   boolean notHappy = !engineer.isHappy();
   if (!notHappy) {
       happyEngineers++;
   }
   if (notHappy) {
       notHappyEngineers++;
   }
   ```

   can easily be:

   ```
   if (engineer.isHappy()) {
       happyEngineers++;
   } else {
       notHappyEngineers++;
   }
   ```

   or to even remove the `notHappyEngineers` variable:

   ```
   private boolean areEngineersHappy (List<Engineer> engineers) {
       int happyEngineers = 0;
       for (Engineer engineer : engineers) {
           if (engineer.isHappy()) {
               happyEngineers++;
           }
       }
       return engineers.size() / 2 < happyEngineers;
   }
   ```

If you are looking for [java](/questions/tagged/java) standard conventions, [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) would be a good place to start. It is quite outdated, so if you are looking for more up-to-date conventions, look [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/javacodeconventions.pdf).

Comment: you are counting not happy engineers `if (!engineer.isHappy()) {
            happyEngineers++;
        }`

Comment: That section is an English Language problem, as well as a code problem. Avoid double negatives!

Comment: @MAG good catch, will fix it.

Comment: `Java conventions require indents to be 4-spaced, not 2-spaced, like almost any other language` - Citation needed! I've worked with plenty of projects, in C, Java, whatever, that wanted 2-space indents. My company currently uses 2-space indents. The size of indent is not important, as long as it's self-consistent, and meshes with the style of whatever other code is nearby.

Comment: @amalloy edited answer to contain that.

Comment: @MannyMeng I'd go with the name `isMajorityHappy` rather than `majorityEngineersHappy` as it is already clear from the method parameters that we're talking about engineers. And since happiness isn't very engineer-specific, I'd probably end up with an interface `Mood` with method `isHappy`, which is then implemented by the class `Engineer`.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers are fine, but I'd like to complete these with a simple point : when you use `var++`, your variable is incremented after the instruction ends.
So, if you have :

```
int var = 12;
int result = var++; // Here, result is 12, whereas var is 13
```

You should consider using :

```
int var = 12;
int result = ++var; // Here, both result and var are 13
```

It can make your code clearer, especially when accessing an array.

```
// array = [12, 32, 42]
int t = 0;
System.out.println(array[t++]); // Prints 12, and afterwards, t is 1
System.out.println(array[++t]); // Prints 42, t is immediately 2
```

(Plus, it makes you save some operations on your CPU, but it's far-far-fetched !)

Comment: This doesn't address any of the question. Pre or post-decrement won't make a difference, and it doesn't use any arrays. Furthermore, where it doesn't make a difference, post-increment is used more commonly, so using pre-increment for no reason is *less* clear.

Comment: Using post-increment should be considered when you need to use this feature, otherwise it is useless, and a source of error (when looping on an array), and the fact that more people are used to it is not a good point. My answer was a tip to make OP think of the best practices, it could have been a comment to its post but I wanted to add examples.